# work around for CSS scrollbar width

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I am trying to give width to scrollbar which work in chrome but not in internet explorer. DO we have any work around for scrollbar code to assign width which work in internet explorer?

```
.flexcroll {
    scrollbar-face-color: gray;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #808080;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-track-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #000;
}

    .flexcroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 12px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no ways to implement it in Firefox/I.E.

Firefox doesnt not have an webkit equivalent property!

in I.E colors can be changed. So it provides limited editability !

But, [DOWNLOAD LINK](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/m-custom-scrollbar-plugin.zip) -> here is a custom scrollbar JS script that is cross-browser compatible.

**NOTE:** It is known to slow down though!